# Rounding Inside razor MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, rounding

I am doing some arithmetic calculation inside Razor view as below

```
decimal n = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.np_claim_dtls[i].PROV_PRICE);
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.np_claim_dtls[i].DISCOUNT_AMOUNT);
<text> @(n-d) </text>
```

its giving me result as below

```
923.0340000000000
```

expected result is

```
 923.03
```

How can i use rounding inside razor? Please help

Comment: Math.floor or Math.Ceiling? You might what to out the logic in the controller and pass it to the view.

Comment: @gerdi i need two decimal point also its a collection passing from controller to view

Comment: What are the types of `PROV_PRIC`and `DISCOUNT_AMOUNT`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke its decimal.

Comment: Then why are you converting it to `decimal` - just decorate you property with `[DisplayFormat(DisplayFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]` and use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.np_claim_dtls[i].PROV_PRICE)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can round off the values like

```
decimal d = 100.1255M; 

string s1 = d.ToString( "#.##" ); // 100.13
string s2 = d.ToString( "0.00" ); // 100.13
```

This can also be done in the controller rather than view. Exposing computations in view is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

This should be working :

```
decimal n = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.np_claim_dtls[i].PROV_PRICE);
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(Model.np_claim_dtls[i].DISCOUNT_AMOUNT);

<text> @(Math.Round(n - d, 2)) </text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Format` currency format `c`

For Example ;

```
@String.Format({0:c},yourDecVal)
```

Comment: I think you need to double quote your format string, ie, `@String.Format("{0:c}", yourDecVal)`?